# Хранение конфигурации в файле

Tags: php

У меня есть список настроек которые пользователь(администратор) может менять в интерфейсе web приложения. Как правило в таких случаях настройки хранятся в таблицах БД для более простого чтения/записи.
Но в моем случаи такой вариант не подходит(нет доступа к изменению схемы БД), поэтому решил хранить конфигурацию в файлах.

Собственно вопрос: есть ли в php механизм позволяющий также просто и не принужденно читать/записывать пользовательские настройки в файл?

Comment: а можно просто в базе хранить json как значение. И всех делов то.

Comment: Как вариант организовать БД в XML. А в PHP полно инструментов для работы с XML. Так же просто и непринужденно не получится, зато парсить руками не нужно.

Comment: речь идет об общих настройках сайта или о отдельных настройках для каждого пользователя?

Comment: @Ипатьев общих настройках, которые должны изменятся через графический интерфейс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents('settings.json'), true);
$settings['email'] = 'john@example.com';
file_put_contents('settings.json', json_encode($settings));
```